# Understanding Sinon.js's stub.yield()

Tags: javascript, sinon

> `stub.yield([arg1, arg2, ...])`
>
> Invoke callbacks passed to the `stub` with the given arguments. **If the stub was never called with a function argument, `yield` throws an error.** Also aliased as `invokeCallback`.

What does it mean "**If the stub was never called with a function argument**" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that if the stub was called, but there was no function in the given arguments, an exception is thrown.

Consider this stub:

```
sinon.stub(fs, 'readFile');
```

Now the test runs these lines:

```
fs.readFile('some-file'); // no callback passed
fs.readFile.yield(); // throws, because the stub was never invoked with a function
```